# module object has no attribute connect

Tags: mysql-python

I have installed Python 2.7 and mysql-python 2.7. I want to execute this code to test MySQL in Python:

```py
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connnect(host = "localhost",
                      user="Bishnu Bhattarai",
                      passwd = "password",
                      db = "student")
cursor =db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from basic_info" )
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    print row[0],"-->",row[1]
```

But it shows the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bishnu\Desktop\database", line 2, in <module>
    db = MySQLdb.connnect(host = "localhost",
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connnect'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the third 'n' from `connect` :)